# How to change the order of banners using the weight module?

Tags: nodes, 7

I have add banners. I want to change the banners order. I have installed the [Weight](https://www.drupal.org/project/weight) module. I have also added weight in content type but it does not reflect in node.

So how can I change the order of banners?

Comment: Are you using them in views?

Comment: yes I am use views

Comment: then sort the view with the weight option.this will solve your problem or expose that field to users so that they can sort the list according to their needs.

Comment: you don't need `weight module` to do this. add one `integer field` with numeric weight  on your `content type` and then sort the content in views based on this integer value.

Answer (score -1):

Check out these modules :

[weight](https://www.drupal.org/project/weight)

> This module adds a weight option to enabled node types. Nodes with
> lower weight will float to the top of lists, while heavier items will
> sink.

[Field_weight](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_weight)

> Customise the weight/order in which fields on nodes can be displayed
> on a per node basis and not just globally per type. Individual fields
> can also be hidden from display.
>
> For any node types that are enabled, a 'Field display weights' tab
> will appear on nodes (for users with adequate permissions). From this
> page administrators can customise the order in which fields are
> displayed on each node by using a draggable table (or manually select
> weights).

[Nodequeue](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodequeue)

> The Nodequeue module allows users to collect nodes in an arbitrarily
> ordered list. The order in the list can be used for a any purpose,
> such as:
>
> 1. A block listing teasers for the five top news stories on a site
> 2. A user’s favorite music albums
> 3. A group of favorite from which one is randomly displayed
>
> Nodequeue provides a simple drag-and-drop interface
> to manually order any queue. Additionally, it allows nodes to be added
> and removed from queues without needing edit permissions to the node.
> Nodes can be added to queues either from a queue management tab or by
> links on the node teaser.